# Override equals on a cglib proxy

Tags: java, proxy, equals, cglib

I would like to use a CGLIB proxy to add my own reusable equals() method to existing objects.

The objects do not necessarily implement any interfaces and I need to be able to cast the proxied object to the original class (without getting the target of the proxy).

Unfortunately, it seems that CGLIB implements its own equals() method and makes sure that only that method is called: there is a private static class (EqualsInterceptor) whose method intercept() implements a reasonable logic to compare proxied objects.
The problem is that this method, at the end, delegates the comparison to the target objects: I need instead to reuse some logic that is not implemented by the target classes.

Using a standard proxy, I was able to intercept the call to the equals() method and execute my logic. The problem is that these kind of proxies cannot be cast to the original class.

It seems that the only way is to rewrite some classes in the CGLIB library. It does not seem a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible using cglib.

You can use another library such as Byte Buddy which allows you to intercept `equals`/`hashCode` just like any other method.

For disclosure: I am the author of Byte Buddy and a maintainer for cglib which are both Apache 2.0 licensed.

Comment: Given that you are a maintainer of CGLIB, I am wondering if you can tell me why CGLIB makes so difficult to modify the equals and hashCode methods. It seems done on purpose, but I really do not see the point.

Comment: I am creating the proxies dynamically and so it won't be so difficult to replace CGLIB with Byte Buddy, but before starting with a complete refactoring, could you tell me what are the limitations of Byte Buddy compared to CGLIB? Of course only if this answer is not too complex.

Comment: cglib has been around a while and I have only helped to manintain it at a minimum to support legacy applications in the past years. This is a decision that was made year's back to support proxies in sets/maps.

Byte Buddy is a fully fledged byte code generator and manipulator. There is nothing that you can do in cglib that Byte Buddy cannot do but it has a slightly steeper learning curve compared to cglib.