# how to check if object instances using SCOPE_PROTOTYPE and ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS in Spring are different?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proxy, cglib

I have two beans `PersonDAO` and `JdbcConnection` with dependency on each other. The `PersonDAO` bean is a singleton bean using `@Component`. But the `JdbcConnection` is a `prototype` and because it is injected inside the `PersonDAO` I am using `proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` to ensure that it is a different instance (not a singleton).

```
import com.github.felipegutierrez.explore.spring.basics.beans.JdbcConnection;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
public class PersonDAO {
    @Autowired
    private JdbcConnection jdbcConnection;
    public PersonDAO(JdbcConnection jdbcConnection) {
        this.jdbcConnection = jdbcConnection;
    }
    public JdbcConnection getJdbcConnection() {
        return jdbcConnection;
    }
    public void setJdbcConnection(JdbcConnection jdbcConnection) {
        this.jdbcConnection = jdbcConnection;
    }
}

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ScopedProxyMode;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class JdbcConnection {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JdbcConnection.class);
    public JdbcConnection() {
        // LOGGER.info("This is my JdbcConnection that is not a singleton bean.");
    }

}
```

When I print the object instance of them the `PersonDAO` is a singleton and the `JdbcConnection` is a different instance. But the hashcode of the `JdbcConnection` says that it is a singleton. Why is that?

```
ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(ExploreSpringApplication.class, args);

PersonDAO personDAO01 = applicationContext.getBean(PersonDAO.class);
PersonDAO personDAO02 = applicationContext.getBean(PersonDAO.class);

LOGGER.info("DAO 01: {}, {}, JDBCConnection: {}, {}", personDAO01, personDAO01.hashCode(), personDAO01.getJdbcConnection().hashCode(), personDAO01.getJdbcConnection());
LOGGER.info("DAO 02: {}, {}, JDBCConnection: {}, {}", personDAO02, personDAO02.hashCode(), personDAO02.getJdbcConnection().hashCode(), personDAO02.getJdbcConnection());
```

output `JDBCConnection` of `DAO01` and `DAO02` has the same hashcode: `1596179075` but actually they are different instances: `JdbcConnection@58a55449` and `JdbcConnection@5949eba8`:

```
2021-03-08 18:13:29.527  INFO 10329 --- [           main] c.g.f.e.spring.ExploreSpringApplication  : DAO 01: 1187972599, com.github.felipegutierrez.explore.spring.basics.dao.PersonDAO@46cf05f7
2021-03-08 18:13:29.527  INFO 10329 --- [           main] c.g.f.e.spring.ExploreSpringApplication  : DAO 01 JDBCConnection: 1596179075, com.github.felipegutierrez.explore.spring.basics.beans.JdbcConnection@58a55449
2021-03-08 18:13:29.529  INFO 10329 --- [           main] c.g.f.e.spring.ExploreSpringApplication  : DAO 02: 1187972599, com.github.felipegutierrez.explore.spring.basics.dao.PersonDAO@46cf05f7
2021-03-08 18:13:29.529  INFO 10329 --- [           main] c.g.f.e.spring.ExploreSpringApplication  : DAO 02 JDBCConnection: 1596179075, com.github.felipegutierrez.explore.spring.basics.beans.JdbcConnection@5949eba8
```

Comment: How did you implement the `hashCode` for `JdbcConnection`? It might be that the proxy simply does not delegate `hashCode` to the proxied object, so what you're seeing as `hashCode` is simply the proxy's own `hashCode` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring uses CGLIB by default when creating a proxy for the target prototype object. It seems this is a [limitation by CGLIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57481209/override-equals-on-a-cglib-proxy) where the `hashCode()` and `equals` methods are always intercepted by special interceptors that do comparison in such a way that does not go through the target object.

If you switch to [JDK interface-based proxies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection-proxies), which requires that `JdbcConnection` implements an interface, you can declare `hashCode()` and `equals()` in the interface:

```
@Component
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
public class JdbcConnection implements IJdbcConnection {

    ...
}

interface IJdbcConnection {

    @Override
    boolean equals(Object obj);

    @Override
    int hashCode();
}
```

Spring's `JdkDynamicAopProxy` will then call the `hashCode()` and `equals()` on the target object.

and use the `@Qualifier("jdbcConnection")` with the interface on the `PersonDAO`.

```
@Component
public class PersonDAO {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("jdbcConnection")
    private IJdbcConnection jdbcConnection;
```